# How do I get the currently emphasized/highlighted series in basic area chart?

Tags: echarts

I have a basic stacked area chart (line chart with areaStyle set) and need to show a tooltip to identify the series when the user places the mouse over one of the series areas. This is a basic need, nothing fancy, but I'm finding it nearly impossible to do in ECharts.

I've already concluded that only an 'axis' tooltip will work because the 'items' (datapoints) only exist at the top edge of a series's painted area, not within the area itself, so won't trigger. But 'axis' tooltips do not have any obvious way to know which series is being hovered over.

What I've tried:

Given that on hover I can see ECharts highlighting the entire series area with a color shift, ECharts must have a concept of the "currently highlighted series". So I've tried:

1. Listening for the 'highlight' event and setting a variable that the axis tooltip can then refer to. But the 'highlight' event does not fire reliably/consistently when moving the mouse back and forth between series.
2. I've tried exploring chart.getModel().getSeries() object tree but cannot find anywhere in the model how to identify which series is active.
3. I've also explored the possibility of setting chart.getZr().on('mousemove') to get the mouse offsetX/Y and using chart.convertFromPixel to calculate the interpolated x/y data values under the mouse and then walk through my source data, including stacking logic, to reconstruct which series should be visible under those x/y values. But this seems way too much work for such a simple task.

Surely there is some way to either find out what series area is visible under a given x/y index, or even better, simply what series is currently highlighted??

**UPDATE: I managed to find a very hacky workaround, but surely there's a better way. Here's how I did it:

```
// whenever the mouse moves over the chart, update our tooltip info
 chartObj.getZr().on('mousemove', e => {

   // set a small delay before continuing to ensure that series highlight/emphasis-state has already taken effect within Echarts. A single tick is not enough.
   let zrTimeout = setTimeout(() => {

     // get the polyline/polygon drawing element from the ZRender component which is servicing a series and is in emphasis/highlight state
     const seriesPolyShape = chartObj.getZr().storage._displayList.find(d => d.currentStates[0] === "emphasis" && d.parent?.parent?.__ecComponentInfo?.mainType === "series")

     // get the series index
     highlightedSeriesIndex = seriesPolyShape?.parent?.parent?.__ecComponentInfo?.index

   },20)
 })
```

Comment: Appreciate the update. Amazingly, this still isn't supported in a friendly way. I can't see any other way than through zr event.

Answer (score 0):

Echarts has a number of events https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.highlight

```
Instance.on('highlight', {seriesIndex: 1}, (e) => {
  // Do something ...
})
```

Tutorial: https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Events%20and%20Actions%20in%20ECharts

Also you can take a look on links collection in my profile (not ads).

Comment: The highlight event only fires when hovering over the legend. It does not fire when hovering over the series in the chart itself.

Comment: Paul, it's only example to show you the direction. Have you read the tutorial? /o\

http://jsfiddle.net/b6yr1u79/

Comment: yes I have. I'm about 6 month into development and the weeds. I think there's a bug/gap in the event emitting here. Attaching the highlight event listeners to the chart instance object works great when hovering over the series labels in the legend, but not when hovering over the series lines in the chart itself, even though they do enter the highlight/emphasis state. Bypassing ECharts and using ZRender to listen and interrogate state seems to be the only workaround.

Comment: Yes, you are right, Echarts has few blind zones and the only way to capture events is zRender. In most cases this is not required, but your case seems to be the exception to the rule.

Answer (score 0):

Echarts 5.2.2 introduced [triggerLineEvent](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.triggerLineEvent), which enables `mouseover` and `mouseout` events on the line, regardless of the node highlighted.

```js
const myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

const option = {
  xAxis: {
    data: ["Category1", "Category2", "Category3", "Category4", "Category5", "Category6"]
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [{
    name: 'Series1',
    type: 'line',
    data: [5, 20, 36, 10, 10, 20],
    emphasize: {
      focus: 'series'
    },
    triggerLineEvent: true
  }, {
    name: 'Series2',
    type: 'line',
    data: [15, 120, 136, 110, 110, 120],
    emphasize: {
      focus: 'series'
    },
    triggerLineEvent: true
  }]
};

myChart.setOption(option);

myChart.on('mouseover', 'series', event => {
  document.getElementById("highlighted").innerHTML = event.seriesName;
});

myChart.on('mouseout', 'series', event => {
  document.getElementById("highlighted").innerHTML = 'None';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.4.3/echarts.min.js"></script>

<h3>Highlighted:</h3>
<span id="highlighted">None</span>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```